# decompress data in scala using gzip

Tags: scala, file, gzip

when i  try to decompress gzip file i get error:

my code:

```
val file_inp = new FileInputStream("Textfile.txt.gzip")
val file_out = new FileOutputStream("Textfromgzip.txt")
val gzInp = new GZIPInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(file_inp))
while (gzInp.available != -1) {
  file_out.write(gzInp.read)
}
file_out.close()
```

output :

```
scala:25: error: ambiguous reference to overloaded definition,
both method read in class GZIPInputStream of type (x$1: Array[Byte], x$2: Int, x$3: 
Int)Int
and  method read in class InflaterInputStream of type ()Int
match expected type ?
file_out.write(gzInp.read)
                     ^
one error found
```

if anyone knows about this error please help me.

Comment: you need to provide braces for java invoked functions. In particular: the body of a while loop `file_out.write(gzInp.read())`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

working model for gzip compress and decompress in scala :

```
//create a text file and write something ..
val file_txt = new FileOutputStream("Textfile1.txt")
file_txt.write("hello this is a sample text ".getBytes)
file_txt.write(10) // 10 -> \n (or) next Line
file_txt.write("hello it is  second line".getBytes)
file_txt.write(10)
file_txt.write("the good day".getBytes)
file_txt.close()

// gzip file 

val file_ip = new FileInputStream("Textfile1.txt")
val file_gzOut = new GZIPOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("Textfile1.txt.gz"))
file_gzOut.write(file_ip.readAllBytes)
file_gzOut.close

//extract gzip

val gzFile = new GZIPInputStream(new FileInputStream("Textfile1.txt.gz"))
val txtFile = new FileOutputStream("Textfrom_gz.txt")
txtFile.write(gzFile.readAllBytes)
gzFile.close
```

don't forgot to close the files it leads to "truncated gzip input"